# Overriding 3rd party private method in ruby module?

Tags: ruby, methods, module, overriding

Is there a way to override private method from a 3rd party module (contained in gem)? I tried to use prepend but the original module seems to be getting into method lookup chain no matter what i do. Here's simplified example that illustrates the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# some external library
class ThirdPartyGem
  module SeeminglyUntouchable
    extend self

    def basic_interface( something )
      hidden_interface( something )
    end

    private def hidden_interface( bacon )
      bacon.capitalize
    end
  end

  def initialize( food )
    puts SeeminglyUntouchable.basic_interface( food )
  end
end

# my own code
class MyParty < ThirdPartyGem
  module SeeminglyUntouchable
    private def hidden_interface( chunky )
      chunky.upcase
    end
  end
end

MyParty.new( "i wish this was all upcase" )
```

FWIW - Ruby version 2.5.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where, exactly, in your code are you using `prepend`? I don't see it anywhere. All you are doing is to define a new module `MyParty::SeeminglyUntouchable`, but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: What about submitting a PR to the gem owner to make said functionality configurable? Monkey matching, especially private methods, only leads to problems in the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’d be a hacky, but working approach:

```
ThirdPartyGem::SeeminglyUntouchable.send(
  :undef_method, :hidden_interface)
ThirdPartyGem::SeeminglyUntouchable.send(
  :define_method, :hidden_interface, ->(chunky){ chunky.upcase })
ThirdPartyGem::SeeminglyUntouchable.send(
  :private, :hidden_interface)
```